# Best practice for setting objects to reference each other?

Tags: java, object, reference

I am writing setter methods for classes which will reference each other, for example in a parent child type relationship. What is the best practice for handling set methods for objects which reference each other?

Should the Parent set method call the Child set method in an if statement to make sure the Child references this parent?  Is this too roundabout or unnecessary? Would it be better to use assert() somewhere? Thank you.

An example code of how it is now:

```
class Parent {
    private Child child;

    public void getChild() { return child} 

    public void setChild(Child c) { 
        if (child== null || !child.equals(c)) {
            if (child!= null) {
                child.setParent(null);
            }
            if (c!= null) {
                c.setParent(this);
            }
            child = c;
        }
    }


class Child {
    private Parent parent;

    public void getParent() { return parent} 

    public void setParent(Parent p) { 
        if (parent == null || !parent.equals(p)) {
            if (parent != null) {
                parent.setChild(null);
            }
            if (p!= null) {
                p.setChild(this);
            }
            parent = p;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

*IF* you want the model where you can directly get from a child to its parent in a single `O(1)` performance characteristic leap, then all answers kinda suck - your objects are in a limbo state in between (you've severed the connection that links from parent to child but haven't set child to parent yet) for a short period of time, and you can't make this stuff `final` either.

Usually (example: The AST representing java code as generated by `javac`, which is itself a program written in java), this isn't how it is done.

Instead, a parent links to its children, but that's it. Given just a child and nothing else, it is impossible to get back to a parent.

To make that work, enumerate where and how you actually need to make that leap from parent to child (and, worse, where you want to *`public`ly*, allow code that interacts with your graph of objects to change relationships do so via either `child.setParent` or `parent.setChild` - that sounds like overkill and just muddying the waters, causing needless style debates on whether one should, if handed both a parent and child and e.g. one wants to sever the connection, should one call `child.setParent(null)` or `parent.setChild(null)`? Generally if there are 2 ways to accomplish the same thing that are equally complicated, that's a bad design.

Once you have enumerated all the places where it is actually relevant that you go from child back up to its parent, reimagine how that code works. Try to make it work with e.g. a visitor pattern (where you invoke `topLevelItem.walk(someVisitor)` and the visitor gets methods invoked for each child, and can even pass along the parent as argument.

This is exactly how javac's AST structure works, for example.

If truly that is just not possible I suggest you try to be a bit more imaginative. If you do manage to design it and it seems to be entirely unsuitable to the job or needlessly ugly, okay, well, what you wrote mostly works (well, what you wrote will loop forever, but you can make it work). But it'd at the very least eliminate (make package private) either `setChild` or `setParent`.